# How to Split 512 bytes array to smaller pieces?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to split my 512 bytes array, I have a function that looks like

```
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
```

and I have my array called nandtest and the below two lines of code works fine.

```
int8_t nandtest[520] = {0};
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)nandtest,512);
```

but and I need to split the bytes array into two pieces 256bytes array and send it.
when I try to do this:

```
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)nandtest,256);
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)nandtest[256],256);
```

the compiler gives me error because of second line:

> warning: cast to uint8_t*(aka unsigned char*) from samller interger
>   type 'int8_t'(aka signed char)

How to indicate that I want the second line of transmitting function starting from the 256-byte position of the array? Or creating two different 256 bytes array is an only option here?

Answer (score 1):

First statement is correct but for second statement you need to use address of operator as your CDC_Transmit_FS function expects address of the buffer but you are passing value at location nandtest[256].

```
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)nandtest,256);
```

which is same as :

```
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)&nandtest[0],256);
```

To pass the second 256 byte buffer you pass the address of 257 byte using :

```
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)&nandtest[256],256);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take the address of the element.

```
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)&nandtest[256],256);
```

In C, an array referred to by name yields the address of the array (that is to say, the address of element 0 of the array).  When you refer to an element in the array, you're getting the element itself.  So, in the second line your 256-byte example, you're passing the single 8-bit value, whereas the function requires a pointer to the value.